# Cheapest Windows Virtual Server Hosting?

Tags: virtualization

I am looking for a server, virtual one as its cost effective for a small website, I need to have RDP access and FTP access which I assume comes with all VPS. What would be a recommended cheap one? I'm looking to spend £25 a month max or about $50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SF probably isn't a great place for that question, as you are asking for a subjective recommendation rather than a technical response: you would be better browsing hosting specific forums like [WebHostingTalk](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/) and its ilk (they have "offers" areas, if "cheap" really is your only specific requirement).

Even when posting to such a forum, you might need to give more details to get a useful answer. How small is the "small website"? Do you have a rough idea how many visitors you expect and how much traffic each will create? What tools/tech does it use (static files only, classic ASP, asp.net, PHP, some form of database server required, ...).

re: RDC and FTP. I would assume all Windows based VMs would be configured out-of-the-box to allow remote access via RDC. You'll probably have to configure the FTP service yourself though.